# Let Z be a standard normal R.V.. Show that Sgn(Z) and $\lvert Z\rvert$ are independent.

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

This seems intuitively obvious, but I'm struggling with showing it explicitly. My attempt is to shatter $\lvert Z\rvert \in  B$ over the possible outcomes of $\mathrm{Sgn}(Z)$. It goes something like:

Let $B$ be a Borel set.

$$P(\lvert Z\rvert \in  B)= P(\lvert Z\rvert \in  B\mid \mathrm{Sgn}(Z)=1)P(\mathrm{Sgn}(Z)=1) + P(\lvert Z\rvert \in B\mid \mathrm{Sgn}(Z)=-1)P(\mathrm{Sgn}(Z)=-1)$$

I know $P(\mathrm{sgn}(Z)=1)=P(\mathrm{sgn}(Z)=-1) = 1/2$ and that combined with the symmetry of $Z$ leads to the result I want, but only for $\mathrm{Sgn}(Z)= \pm 1$.  Am I even close with this approach?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164806/are-x-and-operatornamesgnx-independent?rq=1

Comment: That's very helpful, thank you.  To be sure; it seems that I don't need to check the condition for an arbitrary Borel set, but rather I'm free to use any generating set. Is this correct?

Comment: Sure, in particular sets of the form $(-\infty,x]$.